# Why is ForObject -Parallel giving null-valued expression but works without -Parallel flag?

Tags: powershell, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

I created a ForEach-Object which works, but as soon as I add the -Parallel flag the loop fails with "you cannot call a method on a null-valued expression". I'm using Powershell 7.2

```
$outputArray = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
$outputArrayP = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
$testArray =[System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
$testArrayP =[System.Collections.ArrayList]@()

for ($i=0; $i -le 1000;$i++){
    $testArray.Add("Hello $i")>$null
    $testArrayP.Add("Hello $i")>$null
}

$testArray | ForEach-Object { 
    $outputArray.Add("Hello $_")>$null
}

$testArrayP | ForEach-Object -Parallel{ 
    $outputArrayP.Add("Hello $_")>$null
} -ThrottleLimit 5
```

The actual code stores database queries in an array that I want to run in parallel instead of this sample code.

Related question [Making Requests in Parallel with Powershell results in "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31081663/making-requests-in-parallel-with-powershell-results-in-you-cannot-call-a-method) where the answer code works also in parallel, but does not answer why my code would fail.

Comment: It's like invoke-command.  You would have to use the using: scope to refer to a variable outside of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ForEach-Object -Parallel` works by forking work off to separate background *runspaces*.

Runspaces are the components that host your *execution context*, including all the variables defined in the current scope, so code that executes in a *different* runspace than the one you're calling the code from will not be able to "see" the variables you've defined.

You can instruct PowerShell to copy a reference to a variable from the calling runspace into the background runspace by using [the `using:` scope modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.3#scope-modifiers) when referring to the variable inside the `ForEach-Object` block:

```
$testArrayP | ForEach-Object -Parallel{ 
    ($using:outputArrayP).Add("Hello $_")>$null
} -ThrottleLimit 5
```